# R program for searching information in one data set and inserting it in the other

Tags: r, merge, dataset

I have two datasets with zipcode information. 
CSV 1---zipcode, age,address, email etc

CSV 2--- lat, long, zipcode, countyname

I want write a code in R, that is able to search through my 2nd CSV and insert the county name in a new column for each zipcode in the 1st CSV.

Comment: try `library(dplyr)
csvCombine <- csv1 %>% left_join(csv2, by="zipcode")`

Answer (score 0):

You should first import both csv files into R by the "read.csv()" and then add the desire column to the second dataframe and then save it in a new csv file using "write.xlsx". Regarding to the searching the indices you can use "which()" function.

Regards,
Reza